# SQL: Replace distinct (numeric) values by consecutive index

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a very large table which I need to export to a text file, so I can read it into a different program (R). To save me troubles of writing/reading large text files, I want to transform one of the columns by replacing all of the distinct numeric values by a consecutive index (the column in question is an ID which just happens to be numeric. It could be a character in a different setting). So I want to replace all distinct values of this ID by a consecutive index (replace the `n` distinct values by numbers `1` to `n`).

My data looks like this:

```
ID        SOMECHAR    SOMECOUNT
---------------------------------
1534561   FISH        2
7537281   CAT         14
4738920   CAT         3
7537281   BIRD        7
7537281   FISH        6
1534561   CAT         10
...       ...         ...
```

and I want to write a table like this:

```
ID        SOMECHAR    SOMECOUNT
---------------------------------
1         FISH        2
2         CAT         14
3         CAT         3
2         BIRD        7
2         FISH        6
1         CAT         10
...       ...         ...
```

1) Can I expect to save a good amount space? I have about 100 million rows and 10 million different IDs, the raw IDs are 10 digits long.

2) How to do this in SQL or PL/SQL? The `REPLACE` command is for strings... Do I need to make a second table as a lookup with every distinct ID and the consecutive index? If yes, how do I get the index?

Comment: The value 1 needs as much disk space as 1534561.

Comment: @jarlh Not when represented as text, unless you're padding larger numbers. See the first sentence of the question.

Comment: Note that compressing the unaltered text file will probably achieve very similar savings. I'd expect that if you implemented this change and compressed the unaltered and altered text files, they'd have remarkably similar sizes. You're effectively trying to deduplicate the text, which is what compression already does.

Comment: @cdhowie, true. (I assumed integer type since I read "numeric" values.)

Comment: @cdhowie I will need to read the text file into another program (R), so compressing the text file will not help...

Comment: You're optimizing the wrong resource. Disk is dirt cheap. You can buy a 1TB disk drive less than $50. Programmer time is expensive. Programmers cost $100/hour. Save time for your developers and you'll save money.

Comment: @BobJarvis Truth. But i work by choice as a scientist in public sector (<<100€/h) and even cheap disk space needs to be formally applied for. Furthermore the problem is less about saving the file for backup, but writing/reading large text files between different programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `DENSE_RANK` as following:

Here is the demo:

```
WITH DATAA(ID) AS
(
SELECT 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 124 FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT ID, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) FROM DATAA;
```

Output:

```
        ID DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDERBYID)
---------- ---------------------------
       121                           1
       121                           1
       123                           2
       123                           2
       124                           3
```

Cheers!!

**-- UPDATE --**

Example of updating the values:

```
-- Sample data preparation 
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    ID          NUMBER,
    SOMECHAR    VARCHAR2(100),
    SOMECOUNT   NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE 
SELECT 1534561   ,'FISH',        2  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7537281   ,'CAT',         14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4738920   ,'CAT',         3  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7537281   ,'BIRD',        7  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7537281   ,'FISH',        6  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1534561   ,'CAT',         10 FROM DUAL ;
```

**-- output before --**

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;

        ID SOMECHAR    SOMECOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
   1534561 FISH                2
   7537281 CAT                14
   4738920 CAT                 3
   7537281 BIRD                7
   7537281 FISH                6
   1534561 CAT                10
```

**-- Query to modify the ID --**

```
MERGE INTO MY_TABLE M
USING 
(SELECT
    ROWID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(
        ORDER BY
            ID
    ) MODIFIED_ID
FROM
    MY_TABLE) MODIFIED
ON (M.ROWID = MODIFIED.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET M.ID = MODIFIED.MODIFIED_ID;
```

**-- Output after --**

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;


        ID SOMECHAR    SOMECOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 FISH                2
         3 CAT                14
         2 CAT                 3
         3 BIRD                7
         3 FISH                6
         1 CAT                10
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I have 10 million different IDs -- I cannot write out all of the IDs in a statement.

Comment: @Edgar The `WITH` expression is just sample data, showing that the query below works.

Comment: the result does not represent the expected one. same id should have the same new id

Comment: @Hotfix, Thanks.. Updated my answer

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly with the `DENSE_RANK()` function!

Answer (score 1):

you can create first new sequence like in `tab_with_new_ids`
and than join it to your table.

TEST_DATA  represents your table

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
     (SELECT '1534561' TXT, 'FISH' AS x FROM DUAL Union all
      SELECT '7537281' TXT, 'FISH' AS x  FROM DUAL Union all
      SELECT '4738920' TXT, 'FISH' AS x  FROM DUAL Union all
      SELECT '7537281' TXT, 'CAT' AS x  FROM DUAL)
-- generate new IDs for the old id
,tab_with_new_ids AS(      
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY TXT DESC)  AS new_id
          , TXT
          FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT TXT
      FROM TEST_DATA
      )
)
SELECT t2.new_id, t1.txt
FROM TEST_DATA t1
JOIN tab_with_new_ids t2 ON t1.TXT=t2.TXT
```

```
3   1534561
2   4738920
1   7537281
1   7537281
```